# Creating WordPress account based on email only submit

Tags: wordpress, email, account

Is it possible to create a WordPress account for users who submit an email (no password or username) through an email collection form?

I am looking at sending the user a link to their email to set a password and setup the account in full. The use case is content locking to signed up/logged in users without requiring them to go through the full sign up process. Thanks

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes", but I'm sure that's not particularly helpful. What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of two options: 1) search wordpress.org for a frontend user registration form that may allow you to customize the password options or 2) simply use a generic form or subscription plugin to collect user info, create the new user on the backend manually and then send them an email with a link to change their password